# pyInstaller not installing for python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyinstaller, pyqt5

The pyInstaller.org website appears to be down while I make this post.

I'm trying to installer pyInstaller for python3. I've tried both:

"c:\python34\scripts\easy_install.exe" pyInstaller
"c:\python34\scripts\pip.exe" install pyInstaller

but both give:

```
PyInstaller\compat.py", line 129
    if sys.maxint > 2L ** 32:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Works fine for python27 Is pyInstaller not compatible with python3? If not, how should I make a standalone app of my pyqt5 scripts for windows?

Comment: There might be some issues with your internet as http://pyinstaller.org seems to be working

Answer (score 2):

PyInstaller 2.1 is not yet compatible with Python 3.x. You'll either need to switch to Python 2.x or wait until the project is compatible with Python 3.x, You can check that on the [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyInstaller) page as it should then have updated classifiers that mark it as "Python 3.x" compatible. Currently the tags are:

```
Programming Language :: Python
Programming Language :: Python :: 2
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.4
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.5
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
Programming Language :: Python :: 2 :: Only
```

Answer (score 1):

An [experimental branch on GitHub](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tree/python3) has been published that works with Python 3.

Just download or clone that and run.

Alternatively, [use this fork](https://github.com/zeyon/pyinstaller/tree/python3), which fixes some bugs, e.g. `--version-file=...` support and PyQt5 multimedia support and print services.

Comment: Thank you! I was having an issue with py2exe supporting PyQt5 media, so I used the fork you suggested. Works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: The link to the experimental branch on github is dead.

Comment: Possibly relevant with regards to link to the branch: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1417

Answer (score 0):

Pyinstaller is compatible with python 3 but it should be instaled specifically for that version, the easy way is like this (windows/linux):

```
pip3 install pyinstaller
```

Put it in a CMD (windows) or in a terminal (linux). Note the `pip3`.
the python installation directory must be in the PATH enviroment variable for both (linux /windows) to be able to use pip.

An easy way toget python libs in the PATH variable is checking the box shown below at the installer.

[image]