# Trying to install pyinstaller, but it shows this meesage:python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: pyqt, pyinstaller, archlinux

My current verios of linux is 3.19.3 - Arch . I looked up for some answers trying to figure out the problem but I could not get any specific answer for the error I get.

This is the Error

> Collecting pyinstaller Using cached PyInstaller-2.1.tar.gz Complete
>
> output from command python setup.py egg_info: Traceback (most recent
>
> call last): File "", line 20, in  File
>
> "/tmp/pip-build-wzwxrat3/pyinstaller/setup.py", line 18, in
>
> from PyInstaller import get_version File
>
> "/tmp/pip-build-wzwxrat3/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/**init**.py", line
>
> 32, in  from PyInstaller import compat Command "python
>
> setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>
> /tmp/pip-build-wzwxrat3/pyinstaller

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error this might help

Comment: Sorry but I really did not get that. It says to download that script and locate the directory ez_setup directory and from that I understand that I should make a file ez_setup.py with that code and the run it. I tried locate the directory and I could not find it. I found somewhere that it should be in usr/lib/python2.7/site-packeges but did not worked for me.

Comment: Are you trying to run for python 3? If yes, than this answer can help you (http://stackoverflow.com/a/29497483/3208614), this work for me.